# trying to require active_support in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activesupport

I have a ruby gem and I want to use the Hash.from_xml method in the gem that is included in rails active_support module. I have the below code in my gemspec:

```
gem.add_dependency 'active_support', '~> 3.0.0'
```

However, when I build and install the gem locally, run irb, require the gem, I am not seeing the methods from active support included?

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or how to debug? Thanks!

Comment: Try to use it with `require 'active_support/all'`. Or if you want only hash methonds use `require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'`.

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: sports_data_api requires active_support/all (~> 3.0.0), active_support/all (~> 3.0.0)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to `require` the methods you need from `ActiveSupport`; they aren't added by default.

As Yevgeniy mentioned in a comment, the way to do this is `require 'active_support/all'` if you need everything - or if, for example, you want only the `Hash` extensions then use `require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'`. Note that this usually doesn't go in the gemspec, but rather in whatever file your gem uses to set itself up.

Perhaps even better would be to `require` the required `ActiveSupport` files in the actual files needing them, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: ok that works thank you. Why doesnt it work when I put it in the gemspec as above? whats happening differently when I require it in the file as opposed to the gemspec? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your gemspec references gems. The gem is called "active_support". `require` references files, potentially from gems. You might've been able to do `gem "active_support", :require => "active_support/all"`, though.